# Snap packages support for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, snap

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on an Atom Z3735f system.

I'm stuck with 14.04 because I have a custom kernel with patches in order to be able to have audio and WiFi support for this system, so I cannot upgrade to 16.04.

Is there any support for Snap packages for this version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Off topic,but from my understanding the openelec 7 image has a patched 4.5.1 kernel that supports atom and bay trail hdmi audio Or you could apply the patch yourself http://pastebin.com/kZyiZMR5 and enable with CONFIG_SUPPORT_HDMI=y in the  config.

Comment: @damien marvellous! I'll try it!

Comment: The `snapd` package has been added to `trusty-proposed` but is dependent on `systemd`, which at this point I'm not willing to attempt. YMMV: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd

Answer (score 10, accepted):

snapd is available for 14.04 now via

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install snapd
```

Please note that you want to enable -proposed if you are using a desktop image (see [Snapd package conflicts with xorg packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878750/snapd-package-conflicts-with-xorg-packages/878770#878770) for details).

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid not. Snaps are only available in Ubuntu 16.04 and snappy Ubuntu Core 16 (and snappy Ubuntu Core 15.04, but snaps have changed since then).

I assume you don't have patches for a newer (xenial) kernel?

**Update as of 01/31/17:** snapd and its dependencies are now available in 14.04, which means snaps can now run on 14.04.

Comment: There's no Bay Trail audio support for 4.x linux kernel :-(

Comment: I'm sorry about that! Snaps use some pretty modern kernel security features.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [snapcraft.io](http://snapcraft.io/)

Repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:snappy-dev/tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install snapcraft
```

Comment: Seems to have dependencies like ubuntu-core-upgrader that aren't satisfiable on 14.04, though.