# Snappy with ros

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap, ros

I'm following [this example on developer.ubuntu.com](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/ros-snap/) to test before I "snap" my own creation. However, at the end I'm not allowed to run:

```
sudo snap install ros-example_1.0_amd64.snap
```

I get the following error:

```
ZOE ERROR (from /usr/lib/snap/snap): error checking HMM file
ZOE library version 2006-07-28
```

How do I solve this? Do I need to set some environment variable?

EDIT: I'm using 14.04 LTS. Is 16.04 required to create snaps?

Comment: Are you able to install other snaps? Can you please include the entire output of what happens when you attempt to install?

Comment: The output is what i posted over: 

ZOE ERROR (from /usr/lib/snap/snap): error checking HMM file 
ZOE library version 2006-07-28

I used the following commands: 
$ snapcraft snap
$ sudo snap install test.snap (this is where the error comes form).

I've tried making another snap from: [link] (https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/tree/master/demos/py2-project) 

I get a similar, but not equal output: 
ZOE ERROR (from /usr/lib/snap/snap): error opening parameter file
ZOE library version 2006-07-28

Comment: Yeah this doesn't seem to have anything to do with ROS-- it sounds like a snapd bug. Would you mind [logging one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+filebug), please? Make sure to include information about the distribution you're using, etc.

Comment: I switched to Ubuntu 16.04 and this is no longer a problem. Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/787418/snap-packages-support-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 2):

Under 14.04 there's another package called snap, so running `snap install x.y` gives the `ZOE ERROR (from /usr/lib/snap/snap)`. You want to do `sudo apt-get install snapd` and then make sure you run the right version of `snap` to make your installation work; call `/usr/bin/snap` explicitly if needed:

```
/usr/bin/snap install x.y
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install snapd`

try this first:
`sudo apt-get install conjure-up`

If it fails, this will do the trick:
`sudo apt-get install conjure-up`
`sudo apt-get install conjure-up --classic`

Cheers,
rivanov