# Snapd package conflicts with xorg packages

Tags: 14.04, systemd, snap, hardware-enablement-stack

I wanted to try snapd on ubuntu 14.04, but there was some dependency problems.

Apparently systemd conflicts with some xorg/mesa drivers I have installed with the HWE packages.

I removed some of them and tried again and it worked. Now I'm able to install and use snaps.

Then I tried to reinstall the HWE packages and get this:

```
chestrada@estacion17:~$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic-lts-xenial is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  snap-confine ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libedit2:i386 libegl1-mesa-lts-xenial libelf1:i386
  libepoxy0 libevdev2 libgbm1-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-xenial
  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-xenial:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial
  libgles1-mesa-lts-xenial libgles2-mesa-lts-xenial libllvm3.8v4
  libllvm3.8v4:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386
  libxatracker2-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-qxl-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-xenial
Suggested packages:
  xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi gpointing-device-settings touchfreeze
  firmware-amd-graphics firmware-linux
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fglrx-amdcccle-updates fglrx-updates fglrx-updates-core libegl1-mesa
  libegl1-mesa-drivers libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles2-mesa libopenvg1-mesa
  libwayland-egl1-mesa snapd systemd xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core
  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
  xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libedit2:i386 libegl1-mesa-lts-xenial libelf1:i386
  libepoxy0 libevdev2 libgbm1-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-xenial
  libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-xenial:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial
  libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial
  libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial:i386 libgles1-mesa-lts-xenial
  libgles2-mesa-lts-xenial libllvm3.8v4 libllvm3.8v4:i386 libpciaccess0:i386
  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
  libxatracker2-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-wacom-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-ati-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-mach64-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-mga-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-neomagic-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-qxl-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-r128-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-radeon-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-savage-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-tdfx-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-trident-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-vesa-lts-xenial
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-xenial
0 upgraded, 53 newly installed, 43 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 406 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

So, installing the HWE packages removes systemd and snapd.

Is there a bug here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thanks for trying out snapd. The behavior you are observing is a known issue (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1650389). Almost all required changes landed, except for an xserver update (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1619142) that is currently waiting in -proposed. We expect propagation to the -updates pocket very soon.

To fix your immediate issue, you might want to enable trusty-proposed and install xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial. That will address your conflicts/downgrade issue.

- [How do I add the "proposed" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49609/how-do-i-add-the-proposed-repository)

Hope that helps.

---

UPDATE:

With https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server-lts-xenial/+bug/1655724 released, the issue should be solved.